# How to execute sh for all the files in current directory

Tags: sh

sh checkemp.sh *

It will just check for one file everytime this command is executed.

where checkemp.sh has only one variable which is filename=$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
for file in checkemp.sh *; do sh $file; done
```

If you want to run them all concurrently, try:

```
for file in checkemp.sh *; do $file & done
```

This executes the command `sh $file` where file iterates over the values
`checkemp.sh` and all the other files in the directory.  It's not clear to 
me exactly what you are tyring to do with `checkemp.sh`.  Perhaps you are looking for:

```
for file in *; do sh checkemp.sh $file; done
```

Honestly, though, you'd be better off writing `checkemp.sh` with an interpreter line and doing:

```
checkemp.sh *
```

and iterate over the arguments within the script.